# SSRS -Drill Down Reports

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

How can we drill down to two different reports ? I have 3 reports designed , 1 Report is Bar chart. If I click Bar chart report it will drill through another report 2. Now I want to make user to choose option to display 2 or 3 as per user interest. Can anyone help me out ? Thanks in advance..